# How can I send Apollo Server errors to Sentry?

Tags: node.js, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'm trying to log errors to sentry but all I have access to is `formatError` option which doesn't include the native error so that sentry can display the stacktrace and more..

Answer (score 5):

The error passed to `formatError` is a `GraphQLError`, which *wraps* the actual execution error. The error has a number of useful properties (see the source [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/error/GraphQLError.js)), including an `originalError` property that exposes, well, the original error. Do note, however, that this will only be populated for execution errors, i.e. errors that get thrown inside a resolver. Other errors, notably validation errors, will not have this field, but will still be passed to `formatError`.

```
function formatError(error) {
  console.log(error.originalError)
  return error
}
```

Aside from using `formatError`, you may find [this package](https://github.com/BrunoScheufler/graphql-middleware-sentry) useful, which used with [graphql-middleware](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-middleware), will do the heavy lifting for you.